# Unit-testing a Stored Procedure who is implemented in WebAPI Ctrl

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I have the following problem. I'm new in unit testing and need to test WebAPI Ctrl with GET-Requests who has implemented stored procedures. The Model are created with Entity Framework who generated code with connection to the stored procedures in my MS SQL Server.

To understand it, here is the generic code:

```
//Controller
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/ds21")]
    public class DS21Controller : ApiController
    {
        private SampleContext db = new SampleContext();

        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<RepDTO> GetByDate(DateTime endDate)
        {
            var res = db.getDayRep(endDate).AsQueryable();
            return res;
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

The generated Model Context of Entity Framework:

```
//Model SampleModel.Context.cs (created from EF)
public partial class SampleContext : DbContext
{
   public SampleContext()
     : base("name=SampleContext")
   {
   }

   ...

   public DbSet<DS21> DS21s { get; set; }

   public virtual ObjectResult<RepDTO> getDayRep(Nullable<System.DateTime> endDate)
   {
      var endDateParameter = endDate.HasValue ?
          new ObjectParameter("endDate", endDate) :
          new ObjectParameter("endDate", typeof(System.DateTime));

      return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<RepDTO>("getDayRep", endDateParameter);
   }
```

That's the Model DTO:

```
public partial class RepDTO
{
   public System.DateTime datum { get; set; }
   public string articleNr { get; set; }
   public string fname { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know how to test the WebAPI Controllers like the sample code above?! Can anyone give me some help? I've tried to combine [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2) but the author doesn't use stored procedures in his article.

Comment: The key here is not that the author isn't using a sproc, but rather that you need to inject your context dependency into your controller, so it can be mocked out in your tests.

Comment: @YannickMeeus How can I do that?

Comment: What is the purpose of this test? That the sp can return a result? In that case I dont see a point in mocking the context. Also, I dont see a point in having a test for this at all since there is no logic being executed.